# Is it possible to send a MessageBox over a network in C# - Without having any listening software on the receiving side?

Tags: c#, networking, send, messagebox

So far, I've found plenty of ways to send and receive files over a network (mostly from this site), but I haven't been able to find a tutorial on how to do one with no listening software on the receiving side.

**Example:**

I want to send a messagebox with the title Hello, and the body There.

Normally, I would write out `MessageBox.Show("Hello","There");`

However, I want to be able to send the `MessageBox` over a network.

How would I do this, keeping in mind that:

- Neither of the computers have admin privileges
- I'm using windows 7 on both computers
- The receiving side wouldn't have listening software on it.

Thanks in advance for anyone who helps me with this problem.

**EDIT:** It doesn't HAVE to be a `MessageBox`, I could make a forum that looks like one.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to ask "How can I make a messagebox appear on a remote machine?" Otherwise I dunno, take a screenshot and email it?

Comment: @asawye Yes, but without a program to listen for it to appear on the receiving end of it.

EDIT: It would need to be in messageBox form.

Comment: No, but why would you want to do such a thing? What are you actually trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I think you are going to struggle without having admin privileges. Windows does have a messaging service that can be used to send messages. You might want to give it a try and somehow implement that into your application: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168893

Comment: @Lock I think that would qualify as a "listening software"

Comment: If it's built into windows, it would work with me. I just need it so that the person on the receiving side would have to do NOTHING to their computer.

Comment: The ability to execute arbitrary code on a another machine on a network without admin privileges to the machine would be a nightmare.

Comment: @Minicl55, it **sounds** as you want to write some malware that pushes ads to people... You likely have good-intentional reason to seek what you are asking, but this reason somehow does not appear in your posts. I.e. the reason could be "I want to notify everyone about update to my code" or "Provide immediate help to a person" or "Show latest company policy"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No, that's not why. Besides, a messageBox can't push an ad to someone. It can push a link to an ad... but not the ad itself.

Comment: Minicl55 I'm not sure you are understanding the objections - If you can make a messagebox appear you can run anything. Malware, trojans, virus, ad spam, steal files, the worlds your oyster. Can you understand why this is not possible?

Answer (score 3):

It's like saying, "Can I force you to do what I tell you, even if you're not listening to what I'm saying?"

To which the answer is, obviously, no.

If the other guy isn't plannig to respond to what you're saying, then, well, he won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a MessageBox, as that would be a pretty big loophole.

If you were using Windows XP, you might be able to use the "net send" command from the command line (hence callable in some way from a C# program, or from a batch file; whatever floats your boat), depending on the configuration of the machines.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx

There was an equivalent program called msg.exe in Windows Vista, but it was removed altogether in Windows Seven.

-

In short, not with Windows Seven no.

Answer (score 1):

You can shell out and call PsExec from Sysinternals to both copy and then run a program on a remote machine on your network - the program could be a listener you write or it could just be a program that displays a message it was given on the command line.  PsExec isn't doing anything you couldn't do by calling the Windows API & using RPC directly, but that's a lot of work :)
Privileges will probably be an issue.  At the end of the day there's no way for a non-admin user, out of the box, to muck with another machine on the network.  You'll need permissions to be relaxed - maybe using group policy?  But if you have group policy in place, just install a listener using an .msi or a login script.

Are you able to provide more information on WHY you want to do this?  Perhaps there's a better way of achieving the notification you're after.

Comment: I mainly want this as a productivity tool. IT won't give my computer admin privileges (ironic, most of those IT guys wouldn't recognise what 'C#' is). If I can send a mass-messageBox out, it'd be easier than going around to all the people and telling them.

Comment: I think this is more or less reason why it "net send" was removed from Windows... No sane person wants to see tons of messages popping up on the screen. There IM for IM, e-mail/web sites for notifications, but no good usage for in-your-face popup. If you give your actual goal (unless it is "to annoy as many people as possible") someone may suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe my joking suggestion earlier of sending a screenshot in an email was right on the money!

Comment: @asawyer - That's definitely the best solution :P

Answer (score 0):

It is Possible with the msg.exe tool included in windows.
use the command

```
Shell("cmd.exe /c msg * /SERVER:" & ipAddress & " " & deineNachricht)
```

If your PC doesn't have msg, download it from somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking into the code of this project- it used the net send command line program to send messages to remote machines, although i'm not sure how your mileage will go without admin privileges:

http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FArticles%2F9466%2FThe-NetSend-Plus-NET-C&ei=hNOhT6ewH82RiQe--eCNCQ&usg=AFQjCNHzAjhU7SU7kuPSCQBLElR5vb1sIg